# Having issue with codec_g729x installation

Tags: fedora

I am trying to compile codec_g729x but having issue with its compilation

here is the link for that codec
https://bitbucket.org/arkadi/asterisk-g72x

and I am getting below error after make all command

```
[root@localhost@asterisk-g72x]# make all
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/asterisk-g72x'
/bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.    -DG72X_ASTERISK=100 -I"/opt/intel/ipp/include"  -include "/opt/intel/ipp/tools/intel64/staticlib/ipp_u8.h" -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -Iipp -DG72X_3 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=native   -MT codec_g723_la-codec_g72x.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/codec_g723_la-codec_g72x.Tpo -c -o codec_g723_la-codec_g72x.lo `test -f 'codec_g72x.c' || echo './'`codec_g72x.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -DG72X_ASTERISK=100 -I/opt/intel/ipp/include -include /opt/intel/ipp/tools/intel64/staticlib/ipp_u8.h -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -Iipp -DG72X_3 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=native -MT codec_g723_la-codec_g72x.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/codec_g723_la-codec_g72x.Tpo -c codec_g72x.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/codec_g723_la-codec_g72x.o
codec_g72x.c: In function 'lintog72x_sample':
codec_g72x.c:313: warning: implicit declaration of function 'ast_format_set'
codec_g72x.c:313: error: request for member 'format' in something not a structure or union
codec_g72x.c:320: error: request for member 'ptr' in something not a structure or union
codec_g72x.c: In function 'g72xtolin_sample':
codec_g72x.c:331: error: request for member 'format' in something not a structure or union
codec_g72x.c:338: error: request for member 'ptr' in something not a structure or union
codec_g72x.c: In function 'g72xtolin_framein':
codec_g72x.c:440: error: request for member 'i16' in something not a structure or union
codec_g72x.c:470: error: request for member 'ptr' in something not a structure or union
codec_g72x.c:473: error: request for member 'ptr' in something not a structure or union
codec_g72x.c: In function 'lintog72x_framein':
codec_g72x.c:494: error: request for member 'ptr' in something not a structure or union
codec_g72x.c: In function 'lintog72x_frameout':
codec_g72x.c:533: error: request for member 'uc' in something not a structure or union
codec_g72x.c: At top level:
codec_g72x.c:619: error: unknown field 'native_plc' specified in initializer
codec_g72x.c: In function 'parse_config':
codec_g72x.c:656: error: too many arguments to function 'ast_config_load'
codec_g72x.c: In function 'g72x_toggle_debug':
codec_g72x.c:707: error: 'CLI_FAILURE' undeclared (first use in this function)
codec_g72x.c:707: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
codec_g72x.c:707: error: for each function it appears in.)
codec_g72x.c:711: error: 'CLI_SUCCESS' undeclared (first use in this function)
codec_g72x.c: At top level:
codec_g72x.c:720: warning: 'struct ast_cli_args' declared inside parameter list
codec_g72x.c:720: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
codec_g72x.c: In function 'handle_cli_g72x_toggle_debug':
codec_g72x.c:723: error: 'CLI_INIT' undeclared (first use in this function)
codec_g72x.c:724: error: 'struct ast_cli_entry' has no member named 'command'
codec_g72x.c:727: error: 'CLI_GENERATE' undeclared (first use in this function)
codec_g72x.c:730: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
codec_g72x.c:731: error: 'CLI_SHOWUSAGE' undeclared (first use in this function)
codec_g72x.c:732: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
codec_g72x.c:733: error: 'CLI_SUCCESS' undeclared (first use in this function)
codec_g72x.c: At top level:
codec_g72x.c:736: warning: implicit declaration of function 'AST_CLI_DEFINE'
codec_g72x.c:736: error: invalid initializer
codec_g72x.c: In function 'load_module':
codec_g72x.c:758: error: 'struct ast_translator' has no member named 'src_format'
codec_g72x.c:759: error: 'struct ast_translator' has no member named 'dst_format'
codec_g72x.c:761: error: 'struct ast_translator' has no member named 'src_format'
codec_g72x.c:762: error: 'struct ast_translator' has no member named 'dst_format'
codec_g72x.c: At top level:
codec_g72x.c:812: error: unknown field 'buildopt_sum' specified in initializer
make[1]: *** [codec_g723_la-codec_g72x.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/asterisk-g72x'
make: *** [all] Error 2
enter code here
```

**EDIT:**

After asterisk-devel installation

```
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/asterisk-g72x'
/bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.    -DG72X_ASTERISK=100 -I"/opt/intel/ipp/include"  -include "/opt/intel/ipp/tools/intel64/staticlib/ipp_u8.h" -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -Iipp -DG72X_3 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=native   -MT codec_g723_la-codec_g72x.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/codec_g723_la-codec_g72x.Tpo -c -o codec_g723_la-codec_g72x.lo `test -f 'codec_g72x.c' || echo './'`codec_g72x.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -DG72X_ASTERISK=100 -I/opt/intel/ipp/include -include /opt/intel/ipp/tools/intel64/staticlib/ipp_u8.h -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -Iipp -DG72X_3 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=native -MT codec_g723_la-codec_g72x.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/codec_g723_la-codec_g72x.Tpo -c codec_g72x.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/codec_g723_la-codec_g72x.o
codec_g72x.c: In function 'lintog72x_sample':
codec_g72x.c:313: warning: implicit declaration of function 'ast_format_set'
codec_g72x.c:313: error: 'union ast_frame_subclass' has no member named 'format'
codec_g72x.c: In function 'g72xtolin_sample':
codec_g72x.c:331: error: 'union ast_frame_subclass' has no member named 'format'
codec_g72x.c: In function 'load_module':
codec_g72x.c:758: error: 'struct ast_translator' has no member named 'src_format'
codec_g72x.c:759: error: 'struct ast_translator' has no member named 'dst_format'
codec_g72x.c:761: error: 'struct ast_translator' has no member named 'src_format'
codec_g72x.c:762: error: 'struct ast_translator' has no member named 'dst_format'
make[1]: *** [codec_g723_la-codec_g72x.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/asterisk-g72x'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Anyone have idea about this error, why its giving error about some methods which are not found and what extra tools I need to install to make it working ?

Comment: Try to install asterisk-devel or something similar, it should take care of at least some of the dependencies.

Comment: @CristianMăgherușan-Stanciu i have installed asterisk-devel please see my edit.

Comment: Have you installed IPP?

Comment: @rickhg12hs yes i have installed it

Comment: Which version of Asterisk do you have?  There seem to be preprocessor errors in selecting code paths which assume different member names in 'struct ast_translator'.

Comment: @rickhg12hs i am trying with asterisk-1.4.0

Answer (score 0):

The Makefile seems to be using the wrong version of Asterisk for your install.  From [asterisk-g72x's Bitbucket *Overview* page](https://bitbucket.org/arkadi/asterisk-g72x/overview):

> There are two ways to build the codecs:
>
> 1. Use ./configure. Check the available options with ./configure --help.
>      Specify --prefix in case Asterisk is installed in non-standard location.
>      ICC support is work in progress, please set CFLAGS for now.
> 2. Edit build-ipp.sh (IPP) or build-itu.sh (ITU-T) to select Asterisk version,
>      compiler, and preferred optimization parameters.

Perhaps you need to rerun ./configure or edit the 'build-iXX.sh' file again to get the correct version definitions.

Comment: I have tried with modification but still i am getting same errors as i have described in my EDIT.

Comment: What have you tried?  Please post your `configure` command line and/or your edited `build-ipp.sh` and/or your edited `build-itu.sh`.